# Error de Servidor al ejecutar una página.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo dos archivos: `HoraWebForm.aspx` y `HoraWebForm.aspx.cs`. A continuación sus respectivos códigos:

**HoraWebForm.aspx**

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="HoraWebForm.aspx.cs"
Inherits="HoraWeb.WebForm" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hora.aspx</title>
   </head>
   </script>
   <body>
       <form method="post" runat="server">
          <asp:Button id="ButtonHora" runat="server"
          Text="Pulse el botón para consultar la hora" />
          <p>
          <asp:Label id="LabelHora" runat="server" />
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Este código lo saque de un libro en PDF. El fragmento `</script>` en la línea 7 me parece extraño (¿No tendría que haber sido abierto antes?)

**HoraWebForm.aspx.cs**

```
namespace HoraWeb
{
   public class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
      protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ButtonHora;
      protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label LabelHora;
      override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
      {
         this.ButtonHora.Click += new
         System.EventHandler(this.ButtonHora_Click);
         base.OnInit(e);
      }
      private void ButtonHora_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
         LabelHora.Text = "La hora actual es "+DateTime.Now;
      }
   }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el primer archivo asistido con IIS de Microsoft me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si sea por que se tenga que compilar previamente el segundo archivo, aunque el texto no me dice nada al respecto, asumo que no. No sé cual pueda ser el error.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar lo que tienes en el HoraWebForm.aspx.designer.cs?

Comment: Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/66215/edit) y agregar una imagen de la estructura de tu solución, el árbol de archivos de tu Explorador de Soluciones, considerando también los archivos _*.designer.cs_.

Comment: No hay ningún archivo `designer.cs` . Solo esos dos, y están en la ruta: _"C:\inetpub\wwwroot"_ Que accedo a través del chrome con la dirección que adjunte en la pregunta: _"localhost/HoraWebForm.aspx"_

Answer (score 2):

En tu archivo **HoraWebForm.aspx.cs**

Reemplaza:

```
public class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Por:

```
public class HoraWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: Hice los cambios que sugeriste más los sugeridos por @Flxtr . Ahora me sale el siguiente mensaje de error de compilador:` "No se puede encontrar el tipo o el nombre de espacio de nombres 'EventArgs' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)·` y me señala en rojo la línea 7 del segundo archivo: `override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e) `

Comment: intenta respuesta por respuesta primero, luego las combinas :D

Answer (score 1):

Se debe cambiar `CodeBehind` por `CodeFile` en el archivo **HoraWebForm.aspx** para que quede de esta forma:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" CodeFile="HoraWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="HoraWeb.WebForm" %>
```

Cuando tu solución se basa en un WebApplication debe ser con `CodeBehind`, si se basa en un WebSite debe ser `CodeFile`. Por lo que veo, al cambiar a `CodeFile` también debes cambiar el modificador de acceso de tu clase a `partial`:

```
public partial class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: hice el cambio del CodeFile . Ahora me sale el siguiente error: "Mensaje de error del compilador: CS0260: Falta el modificador parcial en la declaración de tipo 'HoraWeb.WebForm'; ya existe otra declaración parcial de este tipo . Haciendo referencia a la línea 3 del segundo archivo: "public class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: @Fran.J ¿sí cambiaste `public class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page` por `public partial class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page`? Nota que la se agrega la palabra `partial` :)

Comment: Al parecer tiene muchos errores el código. Ahora me sale el siguiente error: _"Mensaje de error del compilador: CS0102: El tipo 'HoraWeb.WebForm' ya contiene una definición para 'ButtonHora'_
 . Haciendo referencia a la línea 5 del segundo archivo: _"protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ButtonHora;_

Comment: Ese ya es un error diferente, y como tal el problema principal ha sido solucionado. En tu archivo aspx.cs borra justo esa línea `protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ButtonHora;`

Comment: Me sigue saliendo error tras error. Sería bueno si lo probaran uds mismos. Por que ya me llené de diversas respuestas y diversos mensajes de error, gracias de todos modos. ¿El cambio de CodeBehind tuvo sentido? por que en el libro dice: _"Nuestra primera aplicación web"_

Comment: Sin el proyecto completo es difícil probar, no se podría replicar el escenario. Las respuestas que damos es con base en nuestra en nuestra experiencia y las investigaciones que realizamos en el momento tomando como referencia los errores presentados. Me temo que no es posible probarlo *por nosotros mismos*

Answer (score 1):

Me sucedía lo mismo, lo único que tienen que hacer es que, en su servicio, se devuelva `null`.

Cuando lo lleven a una variable, donde se vaya a implementar, sería como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```cs
var aux= Cliente.Consultardocumentoscontrato(numContrato);

if (aux.Length > 0) // si es mayor a 0 es porque tiene datos 
    GridView3.DataSource = aux;
else
    GridView3.DataSource = null;

GridView3.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pon lo que tienes en las líneas 1 y 2 en una sola línea y poniendo CodeFile:

```
<%@Page language="c#" CodeFile="HoraWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="HoraWeb.WebForm" %>
```

Si no te funciona, cambia el nombre `WebForm` del .cs por otro ... por ejemplo `MiForm` y lo pones también en el .aspx.

Comment: hice el cambio del `CodeFile` . Ahora me sale el siguiente error: _"Mensaje de error del compilador: CS0260: Falta el modificador parcial en la declaración de tipo 'HoraWeb.WebForm'; ya existe otra declaración parcial de este tipo_ . Haciendo referencia a la línea 3 del segundo archivo: _"public class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page_

Comment: Necesitaría ver el .cs completo para ver las declaraciones y funciones. Sin ver todo, es un poco difícil de replicar.